# How can I combine mapped values to observable array?

Tags: rxjs

I have an array of object that I need to get only trainingName and numOfLikes from each object.
I did this with map but I want to do the exact thing with observables without `res.map`:

```
this.postsService
      .fetchAll()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((res) =>
          of(
            res.map((post) => {
              return { trainingName: (post.trainingID as ITraining).name, numOfLikes: post.numOfLikes };
            })
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((res) => {
        this.data = res;
    }
```

tried the folowing:

```
this.postsService
      .fetchAll()
      .pipe(
        switchMap((res) => from(res)),
        mergeMap((post) => of({ trainingName: (post.trainingID as ITraining).name, numOfLikes: post.numOfLikes })),
        concatMap((res) => of(res)) 
// here I want to wait for all elements of the array to be transformed to the correct format and emit the completed array, but I get them one by one
```

which operator should I use to do that in the rxjs way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example does two very similar things. The first using Array#map and the second uses RxJS#map to do the same thing. Print the numbers from 2 to 7

```js
from(
  [1,2,3,4,5,6].map(x => x + 1)
).subscribe(console.log);

from([1,2,3,4,5,6]).pipe(
  map(x => x + 1)
).subscribe(console.log);
```

In general, turning an array into a stream and then back into an array is a bit of a code smell.

BUT, if you want to do it anyway, you can do this:

This:

```js
this.postsService.fetchAll().pipe(
  map(res => res.map(post => ({ 
    trainingName: (post.trainingID as ITraining).name, 
    numOfLikes: post.numOfLikes 
  })),
).subscribe(res => this.data = res);
```

becomes

```js
this.postsService.fetchAll().pipe(
  switchMap(res => res),
  map(post => ({ 
    trainingName: (post.trainingID as ITraining).name, 
    numOfLikes: post.numOfLikes 
  })),
  toArray()
).subscribe(res => this.data = res);
```